# SUMIFS with Substring

Tags: string, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm using SUMIFS function to compute commissions based on invoice data.  One of the fields I need to check has a product code with many meanings based on position of the data within the code.

For example, product code of "NCH - R - OTF - CH"  indicates owner of product is NCH, R meaning Retail, OTF meaning Off the Shelf, and CH meaning commission on Chinese Herbs.

I need to add additional condition in my current SUMIFs function to check if the product code in column “D” has commission code of "CH".  I need to only check the last two characters of the product item code.

```
=SUMIFS('Invoice Items'!$M$2:$M$30000,'Invoice Items'!$F$2:$F$30000,"Product",'Invoice Items'!$A$2:$A$30000,"=Paid")
```

Comment: You could add a new column which takes the last field of the product code and then use this new column in your sumifs

Answer (score 1):

You can add

`'Invoice Items'!$D$2:$D$30000, "*CH"`

as a set of criteria to SUMIFS

it will look like:

`=SUMIFS('Invoice Items'!$M$2:$M$30000,'Invoice Items'!$F$2:$F$30000,"Product",'Invoice Items'!$A$2:$A$30000,"=Paid",'Invoice Items'!$D$2:$D$30000, "*CH")`